# Different RouterModule configurations for same URL

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Consider this code:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot([
  
    { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },

    { path: '', loadChildren: 'app/admin.module#AdminModule', canLoad: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [HomeGuard] },
  
  ])],
  providers: [
    AuthGuard, // return true if user is Authorized 
    HomeGuard  // return true if user is NOT Authorized
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild([
  
    { path: '', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'account', component: AccountComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },

  ])],
  providers: [
    AuthGuard, // return true if user is Authorized 
  ]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

When I listen to Router events with: `this.router.events.subscribe(console.log);`  (if I'm NOT authorized) I can see `NavigationCancel` event with message:

> "Cannot load children because the guard of the route "path: ''" returned false"

If I am authorized `RoutesRecognized` event is fired, as expected.

As I understand it, Router goes through provided routes and tries to recognize active one. If it does recognize the route, it then checks guards, loads components, etc.

#### My question is: HOW Router recognizes specific route?

Is it by path/url only? Or does it consider any other parameters?

Is there another solution for this (other then renaming path for `HomeComponent`)?

Answer (score 2):

The router just compares the url with the `path` parameters of the routes of the configurations.

It takes the first root route where the start of the url matches, then it continues with the child routes of the matching root route with the remaining part of the url (the url where the `path` of the matching root route was removed at the beginning).
This is continued until the remaining URL is empty and no child routes with `path: ''` (empty path) exist.

A way would be to reconfigure the router (`resetConfig()`) for example when `AuthGuard` returns true.

Comment: Thanks @Günter, **"...and no child routes with path: '' (empty path) exist"** is interesting... Can we nest child routes with empty paths? In my case routes fo HomeComponent and DashboardComponent - can I make one a child of the other, even though they have same `path: ""`?

Comment: I considered this but I got a stack overflow in my head ;-) If you don't use `pathMatch: 'full'` (default is 'prefix') then you can have child routes with empty path as well. I don't know if this could lead to a solution.

Comment: Nesting didn't work in my case: `Invalid configuration of route '': children and loadChildren cannot be used together` and if I swap parent/child, Guard is blocking the child... I'll try with `resetConfig()`.