# Angular 2 router CanActivate how to redirect to 404 but still show the url being visited

Tags: angular, angular-router-guards

Here's my scenario:

A user visits a route called `/protected`. In my CanActivate guard, I check whether the user is logged in. If they are not logged in, I want to **render** my `404` route, **but still show** `/protected` in the address bar. I want users to be unable to distinguish a protected page from a non-existent page.

This is what I tried and does not work.

```
@Injectable()
export class LoggedInGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router, private userService: UserService) {}

  canActivate() {
    if (this.userService.getUser()) return true;

    this.router.navigate(['/404']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

After routing, the url in the address bar will show `/404`, but I want it to show `/protected`.

Changing to `this.router.navigate(['/404'], { skipLocationChange: true });` also does not work because the url in the address bar will be the previous url, not `/protected`.

My question is: how do you render a **different component** if the user is not logged in while still keeping the url that they were trying to visit in the address bar?

Comment: I think you can do that by using two router outlets in the same template this way you switch between the two different component without changing the route. can you create a plunker with your current code so I can try it?

Comment: I don't want to use 2 router outlets though. I was hoping angular had a flag or something for doing this that I'm not aware of.

Comment: I think your answer is here [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928727/angular-2-different-components-with-same-route) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928727/angular-2-different-components-with-same-route

Answer (score 3):

### Problem:

The `/protected` route should render the error component if the user isn't logged in, else render a different component.

### Possible Solution:

Define a route and component for `/protected`, `/error`, and `/page1`.
When the user lands on `/protected`, navigate to `/error` if they're not logged in, else `/page1`.

Be sure to pass `{ skipLocationChange: true }` as the second argument to router to avoid the url from navigating away from `/protected.`

```
this.router.navigate([this.url], { skipLocationChange: true });
```

#### Note:

Adding a `CanActivate()` check for `/protected` determines if you can access the path or not. So it isn't useful in this case because you want to the path to be open but show different content.

### Demo:

https://plnkr.co/edit/6o2DPXmYfNiQEW2Kbr8A?p=preview

### Sample code

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-protected',
template: `
    Location: {{href}} <br>
    Checking Login state ...
    <div *ngIf="url">Switching to {{url}}</div>
`,
})
export class AppProtected implements OnInit {
    url : string;
    href = window.location.href;

    constructor(private router : Router ) {
    }
    ngOnInit(){
        const isUserLoggedIn = /true/.test(localStorage.getItem('isUserLoggedIn'));
        this.url = isUserLoggedIn ? '/page1' : '/error';
        window.setTimeout(() => {
            this.router.navigate([this.url], { skipLocationChange: true });
        }, 2000);

    }
}
```

### More info:

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/NavigationExtras-interface.html#!#skipLocationChange-anchor