# How to have 2 routes with the same url in angular

Tags: angular, routes

Using angular 9 and angular router.

I tried to follow the following thread : [Angular 2 different components with same route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928727/angular-2-different-components-with-same-route)

What I would like to achieve is to have 2 route '', one that move to privateModule if authenticated, and publicModule if not.

so basically,

if I am authenticated and go to [www.myApp.com](http://www.myApp.com) <= PrivateModule
if I am not authenticated and go to [www.myApp.com](http://www.myApp.com) <= PublicModule.

I setup a app-routing.module.ts =>

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    matcher: publicMatcher,
    loadChildren: publicModule,
  },
  {
    matcher: privateMatcher,
    loadChildren: privateModule,
    canActivate: [AuthPrivateGuard],
    canActivateChild: [AuthPrivateGuard],
  },
]
```

then I have 2 matchers, and I do not know exactly how to set them up. since the url is `''` there is nothing to consume and I currently have a infinite loop.

```
export function privateMatcher(segments: UrlSegment[]): UrlMatchResult {
  const key = localStorage.getItem('auth')
  if (key && JSON.parse(key).accessToken) {
    console.log('private')
    return { consumed: segments }
  }
  return null
}



export function publicMatcher(segments: UrlSegment[]): UrlMatchResult {
  const key = localStorage.getItem('auth')
  if (!key || !JSON.parse(key)?.accessToken) {
    console.log({ consumed: segments })
    return { consumed: segments }
  }
  return null
}
```

I am probably using them wrong, or is not the good way to achieve what I want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve the same with [this](https://medium.com/@german.quinteros/angular-use-the-same-route-path-for-different-modules-or-components-11db75cac455) approach

- Considering I want to route to http://localhost:4200/home, Create a home module with private, public modules, define route path to this common module in app-routing as below.

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
 
    {
      path: 'home',
      loadChildren: () => import('./modules/home/home.module').then(mod => 
      mod.HomeModule)
    },
    ...
  ];
```

- home module determines which module to load based on the routes we provide using 
  [useFactory provider of Angular](https://angular.io/api/core/FactorySansProvider#useFactory)

home.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, ROUTES, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule
  ],
  providers:[
    {provide:ROUTES,
    useFactory: configHomeRoutes,
  deps: [AuthService],
    multi: true}
  ]
})
export class HomeModule { }

export function configHomeRoutes(authService: AuthService){
  let routes: Routes = [];
  if (authService.isAuthorized()) {
    routes = [
      {
        path: '', loadChildren: () => import('../private/private.module').then(mod => 
        mod.PrivateModule)
      }
    ];
  } else {
    routes = [
      {
        path: '', loadChildren: () => import('../public/public.module').then(mod => 
        mod.PublicModule)
      }
    ];
  }
  return routes;
}
```

private.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [PrivateComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([{path: '', component: PrivateComponent}])
  ]
})
export class PrivateModule { }
```

public.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [PublicComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([{path: '', component: PublicComponent}])
  ]
})
export class PublicModule { }
```

- The method homeRoutes used by the useFactory provider in the homeModule is only executed the first time we navigate to the /home path, which causes to load the module loaded first time. To overcome this bug, we have to delete the /home path in the Router and add it again as shown below

auth.service.ts

```
  public isAuthorized(): boolean {
    return this.authorizedSource.value;
  }

  public setAuthorized(value: boolean): void {
    const previous = this.authorizedSource.value;
    this.authorizedSource.next(value);
    if (previous === this.authorizedSource.value) {
      return;
    }
    const i = this.router.config.findIndex(x => x.path === 'home');
    this.router.config.splice(i, 1);
    this.router.config.push(
      {path: 'home', loadChildren: () => import('../../modules/home/home.module').then(mod => mod.homeModule)}
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hello, I looked at the medium link, and your answer, and managed to make something that is working even if not perfectly clean.

Still, this answer the question, thanks

Comment: Great! medium link is indeed helpful